# Can I access a TCP socket from a network device driver?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm working on a research project that requires experimental modification to a network device driver (specifically MadWifi).  I'd like to access information regarding the TCP connection for packets as they are processed by the driver (specifically RTTM information).  Is it possible to get this information?

In the specific section of code I'm working with, I have access to the `struct net_device` used to transmit the packet.  I know that I can get access to a `struct net_device` given a `struct sock`, but can I do the reverse?

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. First of all management of TCP is out of scope for device drivers. Why do you need TCP information? Why do you need it in the driver?

Comment: @ldx - Yes, it's definitely not the best long term idea.  However, I do not intend to actively manage the TCP connection, but merely observe the TCP flows (specifically the RTT measurements) to make power management decisions.

Comment: I see - you should implement this in userspace, and provide an interface to your driver to be able to tune power management in it. In userspace it's much easier to access network information e.g. via libpcap.